# WordPress show custom post type on homepage

Tags: custom-post-types

How do I display custom post type in homepage? This is my custom code:

```
// Add the Meta Box - Resorts
function add_custom_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'custom_meta_box', // $id
        'Extra Information', // $title
        'show_custom_meta_box', // $callback
        'resorts', // $page
        'normal', // $context
        'high'); // $priority
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_meta_box');

// Field Array
$prefix = 'resort_';
$custom_meta_fields = array(
    array(
        'label'=> 'Star Grade',
        'desc'  => 'Select Star Grade',
        'id'    => $prefix.'star',
        'type'  => 'select',
        'options' => array (
            'one' => array (
                'label' => 'One Star',
                'value' => '1'
            ),
            'two' => array (
                'label' => 'Two Stars',
                'value' => '2'
            ),
            'three' => array (
                'label' => 'Three Stars',
                'value' => '3'
            ),
            'four' => array (
                'label' => 'Four Stars',
                'value' => '4'
            ),
            'five' => array (
                'label' => 'Five Stars',
                'value' => '5'
            ))
        ),
    array(
        'label'=> 'Location',
        'desc'  => 'Location ex : North Male Atoll',
        'id'    => $prefix.'location',
        'type'  => 'text'
    ),array(
        'label'=> 'Overview',
        'desc'  => 'Overview',
        'id'    => $prefix.'shortDesc',
        'type'  => 'textarea'
    ),array(
        'label'=> 'Distance from airport',
        'desc'  => 'Distance in km ex : 10km',
        'id'    => $prefix.'distance',
        'type'  => 'text'
    ),array(
        'label'=> 'Transfer type',
        'desc'  => 'Transfer type ex : Speed Boat (30 minutes) ',
        'id'    => $prefix.'transfer',
        'type'  => 'text'
    ),array(
        'label'=> 'Total of rooms',
        'desc'  => 'Total rooms',
        'id'    => $prefix.'numrooms',
        'type'  => 'text'
    ),array(
        'label'=> 'House Reef',
        'desc'  => 'House reef Yes/No',
        'id'    => $prefix.'housereef',
        'type'  => 'text'
    ),array(
        'label'=> 'Resort type',
        'desc'  => 'Resort type ex: Honeymoon',
        'id'    => $prefix.'resorttype',
        'type'  => 'text'
    ),array(
        'label'=> 'Resort Website',
        'desc'  => 'Resort Website URL ex: http://www.maldivesa2z.com/',
        'id'    => $prefix.'resortweb',
        'type'  => 'text'
    ),array(
        'label'=> 'Spa info Title',
        'desc'  => 'Attach Spa Price List',
        'id'    => $prefix.'file1_title',
        'type'  => 'text'
    ),array(
        'label'=> 'Attach Price List',
        'desc'  => 'File with title',
        'id'    => $prefix.'file1',
        'type'  => 'file'
    ),array(
        'label'=> 'Water Sport Title',
        'desc'  => 'Attach Water Sport Price List',
        'id'    => $prefix.'file2_title',
        'type'  => 'text'
    ),array(
        'label'=> 'Attach Price List',
        'desc'  => 'File with title',
        'id'    => $prefix.'file2',
        'type'  => 'file'
    ),array(
        'label'=> 'Dive School Title',
        'desc'  => 'Attach Dive School Price List',
        'id'    => $prefix.'file3_title',
        'type'  => 'text'
    ),array(
        'label'=> 'Attach Price List',
        'desc'  => 'File with title',
        'id'    => $prefix.'file3',
        'type'  => 'file'
    ),array(
        'label'=> 'Reservation Email',
        'desc'  => 'Reservation Email ex: rsv@maldivesa2z.com',
        'id'    => $prefix.'resvemail',
        'type'  => 'text'
    ),array(
        'label'=> 'Reservation Phone',
        'desc'  => 'Reservation Phone ex: 00969 000 0000',
        'id'    => $prefix.'resvphone',
        'type'  => 'text'
    ),array(
        'label'=> 'Reservation Fax',
        'desc'  => 'Reservation Fax ex: 00969 000 0000',
        'id'    => $prefix.'resvfax',
        'type'  => 'text'
    )
);

// The Callback
function show_custom_meta_box() {
global $custom_meta_fields, $post;
// Use nonce for verification
echo '<input type="hidden" name="custom_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';

    // Begin the field table and loop
    echo '<table class="form-table">';
    foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $field) {
        // get value of this field if it exists for this post
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
        // begin a table row with
        echo '<tr>
                <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th>
                <td>';
                switch($field['type']) {
                    // text
                        case 'text':
                            echo '<input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$meta.'" size="30" />
                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
                        break;
                        // textarea
                        case 'textarea':
                            echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$meta.'</textarea>
                                <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
                        break;
                        // checkbox
                        case 'checkbox':
                            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" ',$meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '','/>
                        <label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['desc'].'</label>';
                        break;
                        // select
                        case 'select':
                        echo '<select name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'">';
                        foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                            echo '<option', $meta == $option['value'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '', ' value="'.$option['value'].'">'.$option['label'].'</option>';
                        }
                        echo '</select><br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
                        break;
                        case 'file':
                            echo '<input type="file" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$meta.'" size="30" />
                        <br /><span class="description">Current File :  <a href="'.get_site_url().'/downloads/documents/'.$meta.'" target="_blank">'.$meta.'</a></span>';
                        echo '<hr>';
                        break;
                } //end switch
        echo '</td></tr>';
    } // end foreach
    //echo '<tr><td colspan="2">'.str_replace('/wp-content/themes', '', get_theme_root()).'\\downloads\\'.'</td></tr>';
    //dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
    echo '</table>'; // end table
}
// Save the Data
function save_custom_meta($post_id) {
    global $custom_meta_fields;

    // verify nonce
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))
        return $post_id;
    // check autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;
    // check permissions
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))
            return $post_id;
        } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
    }

    // loop through fields and save the data
    foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $field) {
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
        /* // Original save codes
        if ($new && $new != $old) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
        }*/

        if($field['type']=='file'):

            if($_FILES[$field['id']]['name']!=''):
                $newName = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES[$field['id']]['name']));
                $newName = $post_id.'_'.$newName;
                $destPath = str_replace('/wp-content/themes', '', get_theme_root()).'/downloads/documents/'.$newName;
                $done = move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field['id']]['tmp_name'],$destPath);
                if($done):
                    update_post_meta($post_id,$field['id'],$newName);
                endif;
                //update_post_meta($post_id,$field['id'],$destPath);
            endif;

        else:
            if ($new && $new != $old) {
                update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
            } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
                delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
            }
        endif;
    }//end foreach
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_meta');


//featured image
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');


//Custom Resort Type
add_action( 'init', 'register_resort' );
function register_resort() {

    $args = array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Resorts' ),'singular_name' => __( 'Resort' ),
            'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'review'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Resort'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Resort'),
            'new_item' => __('New Resort'),
            'view_item' => __('View Resort'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Resort')
        ),

        'taxonomies' => array('category'),

        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' =>true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        //'menu_icon' =>get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/article16.png',
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
      );

      register_post_type( 'resorts',$args);
      flush_rewrite_rules();

    /*register_post_type( 'travelify_resort',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Resorts' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Resort' )
            );
        array('public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true
        )
    );*/

}
/*
add_action( 'init', 'my_resorts' );
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'my_resorts_messages' );
add_action( 'admin_head', 'my_resorts_help' );

function my_resorts() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => 'Resorts',
        'singular_name'      => 'Resort',
        'menu_name'          => 'Resorts',
        'name_admin_bar'     => 'Resort',
        'add_new'            => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Resort',
        'new_item'           => 'New Resort',
        'edit_item'          => 'Edit Resort',
        'view_item'          => 'View Resort',
        'all_items'          => 'All Resorts',
        'search_items'       => 'Search Resorts',
        'parent_item_colon'  => 'Parent Resorts:',
        'not_found'          => 'No resorts found.',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No resorts found in Trash.'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'public'        => true,
        'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'resort' ),
        'has_archive'   => true,
        'menu_position' => 20,
        'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-carrot',
        'taxonomies'        => array( 'post_tag', 'category' ),
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'comments' )
    );
    register_post_type( 'my_resort', $args );
}

function my_resorts_messages( $messages ) {
    $post = get_post();

    $messages['resort'] = array(
        0  => '',
        1  => 'Resort updated.',
        2  => 'Custom field updated.',
        3  => 'Custom field deleted.',
        4  => 'Resort updated.',
        5  => isset( $_GET['revision'] ) ? sprintf( 'Resort restored to revision from %s',wp_post_revision_title( (int) $_GET['revision'], false ) ) : false,
        6  => 'Resort published.',
        7  => 'Resort saved.',
        8  => 'Resort submitted.',
        9  => sprintf(
            'Resort scheduled for: <strong>%1$s</strong>.',
            date_i18n( 'M j, Y @ G:i', strtotime( $post->post_date ) )
        ),
        10 => 'Resort draft updated.'
    );

    return $messages;
}

function my_resorts_help() {

    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if ( 'resort' != $screen->post_type ) {
        return;
    }

    $basics = array(
        'id'      => 'resort_basics',
        'title'   => 'Resort Basics',
        'content' => 'Content for help tab here'
    );

    $formatting = array(
        'id'      => 'resort_formatting',
        'title'   => 'Resort Formatting',
        'content' => 'Content for help tab here'
    );

    $screen->add_help_tab( $basics );
    $screen->add_help_tab( $formatting );

}*/
```

Comment: is your home page a static page or the posts index?

Comment: You don't need to post all your code, just the code that is **directly** relevant to your question :-). Did you had a look at `pre_get_posts`. Did you try the site search. I personally have handled this ones or twice

Answer (score -1):

To display custom post type anywhere, you only need to add this code `query_posts('post_type=resorts')` just above the while loop. So the while loop will fetch all details of given custom post type and set to the global variable $post.

Here is a sample code:

```
<?php 
    query_posts(array( 
        'post_type' => 'resorts',
        'showposts' => 10 
    ) );  
?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: Never use `query_posts`. It is just an unreliable function which breaks the main query and fails in most instances on pagination

Comment: No, you misunderstood. query_posts() never breaks your main query if you've properly used post data reset functions like wp_reset_postdata() or wp_reset_query() after the while loop of your custom query. 
Also the pagination will work by passing '$paged' variable as an argument to the query_posts function in a specific format .

Comment: Have you seen [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/31545) :-)

Comment: Have you seen this one? http://developer.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/querying-posts-without-query_posts/